# How do I give someone a role for a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot mute users for certain amounts of time when they say a naughty word in chat. I have the trigger set up properly so it can do whatever I want it to when someone says one or more bad words in chat. That code is:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    bannedwords = ['badword1', 'badword2']
    words_in_message = [word for word in bannedwords if word in message.content]
    word_string = ", ".join(words_in_message)
    yourServer = bot.get_guild(SERVER_ID)
    if not message.author.bot:
        if words_in_message:
            DO.STUFF()
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Which works perfectly. the word_string is for the DM I send the user which contains the words they said so they know not to do it again.

Alright! Back to my question. How would I assign a role to the user for a specific amount of time?
I tried

```
await message.author.add_roles(discord.utils.get(yourServer.roles, name="Muted"))
time.sleep(5)
await message.author.remove_roles(discord.utils.get(yourServer.roles, name="Muted"))
```

which would work in theory but for some reason it didn't. That got me thinking however, if the bot were to crash at any point during the user being muted, they wouldn't ever be unmuted since the thread would be closed.

The mute duration being dependent on the thread constantly counting also revealed to me another problem, it's likely that once a user was muted, the bot wouldn't be able to do ***anything*** until the person is unmuted.

SO! How would I make this happen properly? I'm thinking a SQL database, but I don't know how to use those at all, especially automatically with python.

My theory is to make a SQL Database with every person that's muted, the the date and time they were muted, the duration of the mute, and the date and time they are to be unmuted. Maybe I can also include what exactly they said just for tacking purposes. Then, I have my bot read the database every minute and once the unmute-time is higher than the current-time, unmute the user. Higher than because this will prevent a scenario in which case the unmute time has already passed but it didn't trigger for whatever reason.

How would I do this? Is a SQL database even the best idea here?

Comment: You'll want `await asyncio.sleep(5)` to have just that async coroutine wait, not stall everything, but even then you might end up with reentrancy issues, not to mention those people would never get unmuted if your bot crashes during that period.

Comment: To expand on that: yes, to make your bot more crash-proof and more stateless, you'd need some sort of persistence layer, be it an SQL database, a directory full of files, ...

Comment: You could look at this playlist as a basis for your bot: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYeOw6sTSy6ZGyygcbta7GcpI8a5-Cooc

Comment: I see the <sql> tag, but is this really related to the SQL _language_?

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py has [Async tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) you can set it to repeat at a fixed a time period so you can store the time to remove roles in a list and iterate every task loop and remove it if the time matches( you can use datetime module )